# Checking if it is an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm given this subset of the vector space $R^{R}$ of all real functions :  $ \{ f \in R^{R}, \exists n\in \mathbb{N} , (\forall x \leq n) \Rightarrow (f(x) \leq 2) \}$ and I am asked to determine whether it is an affine subspace and find its dimension.
I know that the definition is that an affine subspace of a vector space $U$ is a non-empty subset $M$ such that $M = P + V = \{P + v \in U, v \in V\}$, where $P$ is a point in $U$ and $V$ is a vector subspace of $U$. I am also aware that an affine subspace contains all of its affine combinations.
So my thoughts go like this - If we fix a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and we take two functions $f,g$ from the subset and we take their affine combination we get : $t*f + (1-t)*g$. Now if $0\leq t \leq1$ then both functions are less than two and are in the subset. But if $t \geq 1$ then it doesn't hold.
Based on that I'd say that the subset isn't an affine space but I'm not sure if this reasoning is correct. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your space is simply $\{f: f(x) \leq 2, \forall x \leq 0\}$ (assuming that $\Bbb N$ contains $0$). Not sure whether this is intended or a typo.

Comment: @WhatsUp Well this is how the subspace is described. I also assumed that $\mathbb{N}$ didn't contain $0$.

Comment: Why do you say, "If we fix $n \in \mathbb N,$" etc.? By definition, for any two functions $f$ and $g$ in this set, there exist natural numbers $n_f$ and $n_g$ such that for all $x \leq n_f,$ we have that $f(x) \leq 2$ (and likewise for $n_g$ and $g$).